# How to run a webpack plugin after the build?

Tags: plugins, webpack, webpack-3

```
webpack-version-file
```

This particular webpack plugin can't create needed directory. But once directory is there, after the previous build for example, it runs ok.

Is there a way to run the webpack plugin after the build?

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't able to find a plugin like that, but this one can create directories:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-dir-webpack-plugin